# How do I use XSL Or Operator with Substring Commands?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I've got a program that can create pdfs to xml.  I'm trying to create content nodes based off some of the semi-structured info in the document. Some of the documents have a SUBJECT line and some have a SUBJ: line.  I'd like to get around creating two separate content nodes.  Here is what I have now:

```
<content name="SUBJECT">
  <xsl:value-of
    select="substring-before(substring-after(//content[@name='snippet']/text(),'SUBJECT:'),'&lt;')"
  />

<content name="SUBJECT">
  <xsl:value-of
    select="substring-before(substring-after(//content[@name='snippet']/text(),'SUBJ:'),'&lt;')"
  />
```

I'd like to just have one content node for SUBJECT that combines both select statements with an OR operator.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just combine them into one template:

```
<content name="SUBJECT">
  <xsl:value-of
    select="substring-before(substring-after(//content[@name='snippet']/text(),'SUBJECT:'),'&lt;')"
  <xsl:value-of
    select="substring-before(substring-after(//content[@name='snippet']/text(),'SUBJ:'),'&lt;')"
  />
```

Unless you're planning on getting nodes with both SUBJ and SUBJECT in the same node, this will work OK for you.

Comment: Ahh, didn't know that you could have multiple select statements under a node.  Thanks